# new commands, spacing and italic fonts

Tags: spacing, macros

I have used the `\def` command for several long scientific terms so that I can have an easy shorthand reference and do not have to keep typing them out every time e.g. `\carb` for `$\delta$$^{13}$C` (full code `\def\carb{$\delta$$^{13}$C }`). However if I do not include the final space after the C the output runs into the next word. This is problematic if I use the definition before full stops or ) because it adds an extra space, for example (δ13C ) or [δ13C .].

I tried the `xspace` package which did work for punctuation problems, but it doesn't add a space after words which I would like in italics. I added `{}` in my document and this did solve the problem, but I was wondering if there was an easier way? An example of a define command I have which has this problem is: `\def\geog{\textit{geography\xspace}}` –

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please expand your code to an example which people can compile and which demonstrates the problem. However, `{}` is the standard approach and `xspace` is know to be not without problems. You would, however, be wise to avoid `\def` and use `\newcommand` if you are using LaTeX. Also, why do you have `$$`? This just ends maths mode and immediately begins it again.

Comment: If you really want to use `\xspace`, it should be the very last item in the body of the definition. *Don't* use `\def`, but `\newcommand`; once you do `\def\box{box}` you'll know why.

Comment: that is simply user error and should be `\def\geog{\textit{geography}\xspace}` although personally I wouldn't use xspace (even though I wrote it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, once I put \xspace in the right place it worked! I'll also change the code to \newcommand instead. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a tons of command like \carb. This method is at the end imho quite messy and quite often good command names are already take by other packages. I would use one command, e.g. \sh (for shorthand) with an argument. Beside solving the problem with the space it also allows you to use numbers and punctuations. A simple method is this but you can also use glossaries or acro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{myshorthand@carb}{$\delta$$^{13}$C}
\@namedef{myshorthand@carb-12}{$\delta$$^{12}$C}
\@namedef{myshorthand@carb-n}{$\delta$$^{n}$C}

\newcommand\sh[1]{\csname myshorthand@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sh{carb}, \sh{carb} blblb 

\sh{carb-12}, \sh{carb-n}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `\xspace` but if you do use it the syntax is

```
\newcommand\geog{\textit{geography}\xspace}
```

Comment: I believe that the exponent refers to the subsequent C.

Comment: @egreg I deleted that bit then, but the markup's not great in any case:-)