# Define ''words" and treat them as text

Tags: spacing

I want to define in LaTeX some words. For instance I have this long words: ''contemporaneamente''. So I can define `\def\cont{contemporaneamente}`. The problem is that it is not treated as normal text and so there is a problem in spacing.

If I write ''`\cont bla bla`'' the result is: ''contemporaneamentebla bla''. So I have to write ''`\cont\ bla bla`'' to obtain what I want.

I know also that in order to obtain what I want I can define `\def\cont{contemporaneamente }`. The problem in doing this is that when I want to put the word at the end of a sencence and I have to write ''`\cont`.'' the result is ''contemporaneamente .''

Comment: You don't really want to define such shorthands; when you'll resume work after a month's break, you'll not remember what the commands stand for.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391206/new-commands-spacing-and-italic-fonts